# PHP-Ajax: live search with drop down and assign value onclick

Tags: php, html, json, ajax

I am implementing live search using html input "search" and result should be shown below it so user can select correct name. once customer select name it assign ID of selected name to other hidden input "id". 
below is my code details :

index.php

```
<?php

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PHP Live MySQL Database Search</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").keyup(function(){
    var txt = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
    var personname = "";
    var personID = "";
    if (txt !='')
    {
        $.ajax
        (
        {
            type:"post",    //submit method
            url: "search.php",  //url to sumitted data To
            data: {name : txt}, //Data to be submitted
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            //action on successful post request
            success: function(data)
            {
                //process JSON
                $.each(data.names, function(idx, name){

                    var person = "<p>" + name.name +"</p>";
                    resultDropdown.html(person);
                });

            },
        }
        )
    }
    else
    {
        resultDropdown.empty();
    }
  });

   // Set search input value on click of result item


});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="result.php">
    <div class="search-box">

        <input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off" name="spousename" placeholder="search spouse" />
        <input type="hidden" id="id" autocomplete="off" name="spouseid" placeholder="search spouse" />
        <input class="w3-button w3-block w3-green w3-section w3-padding" type="submit" name="access"><b>Login</b></button>
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

returned data from search.php

```
{"names":[{"name":" xxxxxx","id":3},{"name":"yyyy","id":6},{"name":"zzzz","id":5}]}
```

issues am facing: 
1- resultDropdown.html(person) : only show last item on json

2- how to assign ID on click

Comment: Is only show last item because it is a feature of the html() function.With each new interaction your .html() function overlaps all content. [SEE MORE HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is full code if some

```
<?php

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PHP Live MySQL Database Search</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        font-family: Arail, sans-serif;
    }
    /* Formatting search box */
    .search-box{
        width: 300px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .search-box input[type="text"]{
        height: 32px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .result{
        position: absolute;        
        z-index: 999;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    .search-box input[type="text"], .result{
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* Formatting result items */
    .result p{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-top: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .result p:hover{
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
</style>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").keyup(function(){
    var txt = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(".result");
    var person = "";
    if (txt !='')
    {
        $.ajax
        (
        {
            type:"post",    //submit method
            url: "search.php",  //url to sumitted data To
            data: {name : txt}, //Data to be submitted
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            //action on successful post request
            success: function(data)
            {
                //process JSON
                $.each(data.names, function(idx, name){
                    person += '<p data-id="'+ name.id +'">' + name.name +'</p>';

                });
                resultDropdown.html(person);

            },
        }
        )
    }
    else
    {
        resultDropdown.empty();
    }
  });

   // Get the id of the clicked person
        $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
            //assign the value of person name to search input 
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('#search').val($(this).text());

        //get the id 
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        //set input id "id" value 
         $("#id").val(id);
        //clear search data
         $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    })


});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="result.php">
    <div class="search-box">

        <input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off" name="spousename" placeholder="search spouse" />
        <input type="hidden" id="id" autocomplete="off" name="spouseid" placeholder="search spouse" />
        <input class="w3-button w3-block w3-green w3-section w3-padding" type="submit" name="access"><b>Submit</b></button>
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

assing the html to a variable and then display it after the loop

```
var resultDropdown = $(".result");

success: function(data)
                    {
    var person = "";
                    //process JSON
                    $.each(data.names, function(idx, name){

                        person += '<p class="name" data-id="'+ name.id +'">' + name.name +'</p>';

                    });
    resultDropdown.html(person);

                }

// Get the id of the clicked person
        $(document).on('click', '.name', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
})
```

Comment: thank you @Baracuda078 I have to change .name to .result on `$(document).on('click', '.name', function(){ `in order for user to click